# Google Calendar Integration - Unable to authenticate with API: 401, message='Unauthorized' Home Assistant

Tags: google-calendar-api, home-assistant

Not sure what is going on, but after following some instructions [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NQH0c6YGQqY&feature=youtu.be) to integrate my google calendar into Home Assistant, it works for like an hour, then it doesn’t work anymore. Tried it 4 times, both times just stops working with Google calendar after about an hour, even after delete the project from google and making a new one.

Here's the error log:

> Unable to connect to Google: Unable to authenticate with API: 401, message='Unauthorized', url=URL('https://www.googleapis.com/calendar/v3/calendars/f...[]....75@group.calendar.google.com/events?maxResult=100&singleEvents=true&orderBy=startTime&fields=kind,nextPageToken,nextSyncToken,items(id,summary,description,location,start,end,transparency)&timeMin=2022-05-01T06:00:00%2B00:00&timeMax=2022-06-12T06:00:00%2B00:00')

> 3:34:54 PM – (ERROR) Google Calendars - message first occurred at 3:34:24 PM and shows up 48 times.

when it happens, I click on calendar and its just a blank calendar, when it was previously showing all my entries.

Any idea why it works and then it doesn’t work?

Answer (score 0):

The method you are currently trying to use requires user consent.  You will need to use Oauth2 to request consent of the user and get an access token back.  This token will allow you to access the users data.  You are not currently sending one. It is sent as an authorization header.

```
GET https://www.googleapis.com/calendar/v3/calendars/[CALENDARID]/events?key=[YOUR_API_KEY] HTTP/1.1

Authorization: Bearer [YOUR_ACCESS_TOKEN]
Accept: application/json
```

Comment: thanks for your responce. For some odd reason, it started working and has been for 24 hrs now. The token was always there, perhaps some server issues on Google's part?

Answer (score 0):

thanks!

Turns out there was some server issues at Google. Problem resolved itself after a couple of days.